# Django: Errors when switching DateTimeField into DateField

Tags: django

I'm working on a project with Django.

I used DateTimeField() when I first created some Model. I also created hundreds of instances. Then I decided that DateField was more appropriate and changed it.

when I `migrate`, It was migrated well without any warning messages.

But when I try to access original instances made with `DateTimeField`, I received the following error.

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'13 00:00:00'`

The Error seems to have occured because datetimefield data remains even though format has changed.

But I don't know how to resolve it since I get this errors even when I try to delete existing instances.

I also wonder why this error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Go to python manage.py shell. With for loop change every object's datetime to date:

```
for x in MyModel.objects.all():
    x.date = x.date.date()
    x.save()
```

or if it's not working, and field is nullable, then:

```
for x in MyModel.objects.all():
    x.date = None
    x.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the error occurs even when I call MyModel.objects.all().

Comment: If it is not a problem, drop your database. Delete all migration files. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted all files related with db including db.sqlite
But Is it Okay to delete all migration files and remigrate when I collaborate with my team by github? I'm afraid conflict occurs with past migrate files.

Comment: Oh, yes, it might matter in the future. Don't delete them. Does it work without reseting migrations?

Comment: Unfornately I already deleted all migrate files. Is it Okay to delete past files and accept my migrate files since these are the latest files and reflect all the latest version of model?

Comment: Other developers should also delete migrate files and get yours then. It matters a lot, because migration files has something called 'dependency', and it will raise errors if their dependency is not pointing to existing files. Read more about django-migrations and discuss with co-developers.